# ¿Por qué mi shell en C no corre el comando "ls"?

Tags: c, linux, shell

Tengo este código que es un shell básico de Linux en C, al ejecutarlo funcionan varios comandos como "pwd", también funciona "ls -lh /bin" pero antes de que me muestre el resultado me sale un error con "ls" y no logro que funcione el comando "ls" solo, y no sé qué podría ser.
Tengo todos los includes necesarios y no me presenta errores de compilación, solo al momento de ingresar "ls".

Este es el error:

```
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

Este es mi código:

```
void  parsing(char *line, char **argv) {
     while (*line != '\0') {
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';
          *argv++ = line;
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&  *line != '\t' && *line != '\n')
               line++;
      }
     *argv = '\0';
}



//proceso del fork
void  forkprocess(char **argv) {
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
          printf("Fork failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {
               printf("Exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else{
          while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[64]) {

     char  line[1024];
     while (1) {
          printf(">>");     //shell

      //recibe el comando ingresado por teclado 
      fgets(line,1024,stdin);
      printf("\n");

      parsing(line, argv);

      //si la entrada es igual a QUIT sale
          if (strcmp(argv[0], "QUIT") == 0) {
               printf("BYE!\n");
               exit(0);
           }

          forkprocess(argv);
     }
//return 0;

}
```

Tengo en el main también un método para agregar la función de ayuda al ejecutar ./programa -h, no sé si eso contribuya al error

int opt;

```
//metodo de opcion de ayuda ./jarvis -h
 while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "h")) != -1){
    switch(opt) {
        case 'h':
            print_help(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "uso: %s <comando>\n", argv[0]);
            fprintf(stderr, "     %s -h\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error sale?

Comment: Este es el error->    ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory

Comment: Amigo, ese error es de el comando. Significa que estas tratando de hacer un list en un directorio que no existe.

Comment: No sé cómo corregirlo, he probado varias cosas pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Comment: De acuerdo con @Pablochaches, este no es un error del comando sino un aviso de que ese fichero o directorio no existe. ¿Existe el fichero sobre el cual haces `ls`?

Comment: @Michelle Escribe en tu terminal `ls ''`. Luego de comprobar que esa es la fuente del error, tienes que aislar de tu programa la parte que llamas a `ls` y hacemos el debug desde ahi.